# How the elements of scene.children in threeJS can be accessed?

Tags: three.js

I added some objects to ThreeJS scene (using `scene.add(object)`). I know the name of object and just want to fetch index of it from scene.children.

I tried to use `scene.children.indexOf("objectName")` but it returns -1 index. Can anybody suggest what can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

```
var object = scene.getObjectByName( "objectName" );
```

or to recursively search the scene graph

```
var object = scene.getObjectByName( "objectName", true );
```

Alternatively, you can search by ID.

```
var id = scene.getObjectById( 4, true );
```

three.js r.60

Comment: I just tried as you suggested, but got "undefined". I checked by putting `var object = scene.getObjectByName( "objectName" );` in alert() and got "undefined". Since I don't know much about ThreeJS, but I found that objects are storied in `scene.children`. Every object we add to scene get append to the end of scene.children. So I wrote this code: `var lastIndex = scene.children.length - 1; endElement = scene.children[lastIndex];scene.remove(endElement);` This removes the last element I drew. I need your help to fetch ID of an element from scene.children with reference to object name. Thanks.

Comment: @user2615614 Did you set the name parameter of the object you added to the scene? Some sample code would be helpful in diagnosing the error :)

Comment: Your "accept" rate is zero. Please remember to accept answers by clicking on the check mark next to the answer. Do this for others who have answered your questions, too. If your program is not working, then please make a new post, show your code, and ask a specific question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that something that can actually can answer your question is the following code that I use to clean the scene:

```
while (scene.children.length > 0) {
            scene.remove(scene.children[scene.children.length - 1]);
}
```

this way I don't need to access an element by its name or id. The object are simply fetched from the array with an index, so it's like `scene.children[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You got an alert text as *undefined* because you're getting back an object not a `value/text`.  You would need to alert something like `scene.getObjectByName( "objectName" ).name` or `scene.getObjectByName( "objectName" ).id` i believe.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant docs: [getObjectById](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.getObjectById), [getObjectByName](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.getObjectByName). An important note from `getObjectByName`:

> Note that for most objects the name is an empty string by default. You will have to set it manually to make use of this method.

This could be why you were getting `undefined`. Also, if you are getting `undefined`, trying to access `.name` or `.id` is going to throw an error. If you were getting an object back you would see something like "[object Object]" in the alert.

Another important note I learned the hard way is that the value you need to pass to `getObjectById` is `object.id`, and not `object.uuid`. Also, `object.id` is essentially just the index of the `object` in the `children` array.

Putting it all together:

```
// var object = new THREE.Mesh(...) or similar
object.name = 'objectName';
scene.add(object);
var retrievedObject = scene.getObjectById(object.id);
// or
var retrievedObject = scene.getObjectByName('objectName');
alert(retrievedObject.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

scene.children - return all the elements ( instanceof Object3D ) as an Array.

[ Mesh, Light, Camera ]

Whatever your have added by calling **scene.add(obj)** method.

---

❌ You done mistake

`scene.children.indexOf("objectName")`

you tried this.
It will never work. Because you provided String against Object3D.

Instead of this, you should use this. ✅

```js
scene.getObjectByName('objname');
```

*objname* that you have to set before calling the method. Like this way..

```js
anyMesh.name = 'objname';
scene.add( anyMesh );
```